# How to show servlet Output it on Drop down list Using JavaScript

Tags: servlets, kendo-ui

I got Directory Name From servlet like : `E://Test//Folder1`. But I want to show this output value on Kendo Dropdown list. How to show Folder Name returned from servlet and I am using Kendo Dropdown List.

```
getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
```

Comment: i got my answer :- first get the folder list from URL Using servlet then output set as a JSON format . then in XML we write action name class name with method where we got JSON format folder list then go to html page and in place for URL provide action name . then it will populate successfully . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Get the Folder Directory into JSON Format Using Java Code**

**1. Mapped Action Name with Class and Method on Strtus.xml**

**1. Same Action Name Use on JS Drop down Function URL**